# Extracting text from Http response

Tags: java, json, httpresponse

following is the screenshot of http respone in java -

[image: screenshot of http response]

and following is the text form of response:

```
{
  "LightGingerTheTextResult": [
    {
      "Confidence": 4,
      "From": 0,
      "LrnFrg": null,
      "LrnFrgOrigIndxs": [],
      "Mistakes": [
        {
          "CanAddToDict": false,
          "From": 0,
          "To": 0
        }
      ],
      "ShouldReplace": true,
      "Suggestions": [
        {
          "LrnCatId": 12,
          "Text": "An"
        },
        {
          "LrnCatId": 45,
          "Text": "A"
        }
      ],
      "To": 0,
      "TopLrnCatId": 12,
      "Type": 3,
      "UXFrgFrom": 0,
      "UXFrgTo": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to extract the "text" in the suggestion.

This is my part with json. I am getting final response in "finalResult"-

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try
        {
            StringBuffer response =urllib.urlopen(url);
            String finalResponse= response.toString();
            System.out.println("final response"+finalResponse);
            StringBuffer result=(StringBuffer) json.get(finalResponse);
            //finalResult=URLEncoder.encode(result.toString(), "UTF-8");
            String finalResult=result.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Use some object mapping to map the json to a POJO and then simply access the `text` property of that.

Comment: Or use a JSON parser like [JSON-P](https://javaee.github.io/jsonp/).

Comment: Show us what you have tried to solve this problem. Does it work? If not, what does not work?

Comment: The response is JSON text (as you know since you tagged it so), so use a JSON library to process it.

Comment: Accept response as a string and use jsonpath library. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34117168/3295987. But its better to map json with POJO as you might need other fields as well (if not now, then in future)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java). You needs a library,
using package [org.json](http://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) with

```java
new JSONObject(textOfResponse)
.getJSONArray("LightGingerTheTextResult").getJSONObject(0)
.getJSONArray("Suggestions").getJSONObject(0)
.getString("Text")
```

and your `textOfResponse` I get

```
An
```

Comment: It returned 'Null Key ' as response

Comment: Strange, add some details

Comment: @first with a JSONObject if you invoke `.getJSONArray(null)` or `.getString(null)` you get an `Exception in thread "..." org.json.JSONException: Null key.`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a value of a specific JSON node you can use a [JsonPath expression](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2) e.g. to extract values of all `Text` nodes:

```
$.LightGingerTheTextResult[*].Suggestions[*].Text
```

in your example simplifies to

```
$..Text
```

or just the first `Text` node from the first `Suggestions` node:

```
$.LightGingerTheTextResult[0].Suggestions[0].Text
```

Comment: Can you give me example about how to do this.I searched on internet,but I didn't understand that.

Comment: After adding this code I got "json can not be null or empty" as response

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to first start by retreive the body of your httpResponse object.

```
 String tmp = response.body();   // I assume the callback method has a an 
                                 //argument of type 
                                 //httpResponse called response
```

Then store it somewhere eg:string.

Use gson and use the httpResponse class

like this:
httpResponse rep = gson.fromJson(, httpResponse .class);
This way you can now use the rep object to retreive what ever you want.