# I have created a .json file and want to fetch the data from that json file using rest assured method. How can I achieve this?

Tags: testing, automation, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have designed a Rest Assured Framework where I create a separate JSON file that contains all API endpoints. So, now I want to pull the data out of this JSON file using Rest Assured. How can that be achieved?

Sample JSON file :

```
{
   "data": [{
         "TestCasesID": "TestCase_1",
         "ModuleName": "ABC",
         "TestCaseDescription": "Get Special Offer",
         "GetURL1": "#v1/my/specialOffers",
         "GetURL2": "#v1/my/specialOffers"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you donot need rest-assured to just read values from json. it can not read/parse json files/strings. it need help from other libraries like jackson.

please refer the below answer:-

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111276/jsonpath-with-jackson-or-gson)