# Parse JSON having both Escape & Unescape characters in JAVA using Jayway

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonpath, jayway

I receive the below json as an input to my program:

```
{
    "shopping": {
        "cart": {
            "items": [{
                "iturl" : "https://www.google.com/",
                "itdesc" : "Item’s box includes the below contents:\n a.adaptor \n b.sdfd"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

We are using jayway jsonpath to parse this data and do some processing and return the final value as a string.

when we parse it with the default jsonpath configuration, I get the iturl modified as "https:\/\/www.google.com\/"

Tried changing the JSONProvider to JacksonJsonProvider (by referring [Jsonpath with Jackson or Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111276/jsonpath-with-jackson-or-gson)) and the issue with the url is solved but, the value of itdesc is now coming to new line (due to \n) making it an invalid json.

I cannot specifically handle for each field as the incoming data will be dynamic.

Is there any proper way to parse this kind of JSON in java. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: How do you receive this JSON to your application? As an object or as a String?

Comment: We receive it as a String

Answer (score 1):

Try adding one more escaping level before parsing the string, the string parser's gonna give you "\n" for "\\n".

For example, parsing with Jackson ObjectMapper.

```
objectMapper.readValue(jsonString.replace("\\", "\\\\"), Any.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
{
"shopping": { <-- JSONObject
    "cart": { <-- JSONObject
        "items": [{ <-- JSONArray
            "iturl" : "https://www.google.com/", <-- JSONObject inside JSONAray
            "itdesc" : "Item’s box includes the below contents:\n a.adaptor \n b.sdfd"
        }]
    }
}
```

}

if this data json come from http connection.
this json must be a string format fisrt,
and try using org.json.simple
so do like this :

```
private void readData() {
    String Body = (response json string from connection);
    JSONParser parse = new JSONParser();
    String iturl = null;
    String itdesc = null;

    try  {
        JSONObject shopping =  (JSONObject) parse.parse(Body);
        JSONObject cart=  (JSONObject) shopping.get("cart");
        JSONArray  items = (JSONArray  ) cart.get("items ");
        items.forEach((k)-> {
            JSONObject inside = (JSONObject) k;
            iturl = inside.get("iturl");
            itdesc = inside.get("itdesc");
        });
    }catch ( ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

if this come from file.json combine with reader :

```
private static final File jsonData = new File(file.json);
private void callData() {
    String iturl = null;
    String itdesc = null;
    try  {
        Reader reader = new FileReader(marketList);
        JSONParser parse = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject shopping =  (JSONObject) parse.parse(reader);
        JSONObject cart=  (JSONObject) shopping.get("cart");
        JSONArray  items = (JSONArray  ) cart.get("items ");
        items.forEach((k)-> {
            JSONObject inside = (JSONObject) k;
            iturl = inside.get("iturl");
            itdesc = inside.get("itdesc");
        });
    } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```