# How to update nested JSON in Java with dynamic structure

Tags: java, json, jsonparser

I have a property file, where the user can define full field names, something like:

```
league.firstname
league.lastName
```

Now in my code, I have an incoming JSON, and I want to first retrieve the existing value and then edit the values of fields mentioned in the property file. In this case, retrieve and edit values of **league.firstName** and **league.lastName** fields. JSON looks something like:

```
{
  "_internal": {
    "pubDateTime": "2017-12-10 11:42:23.504",
    "xslt": "xsl/league/roster/marty_active_players.xsl",
    "eventName": "league_roster"
  },
  "league": {
      {
        "firstName": "Alex",
        "lastName": "Abrines",
        "personId": "203518",
        "teamId": "1610612760"
      }
  }
}
```

Now I know I can do something like:

```
// retrieve values
String fName = jsonObj.getJSONObject("league").getString("firstName");
String lName = jsonObj.getJSONObject("league").getString("lastName");
// put new values
jsonObj.getJSONObject("league").put("firstName", "newVal1");
jsonObj.getJSONObject("league").put("lastName", "newVal2");
```

But how do I achieve this dynamically. For example, property file is like:

```
parentObj.child1.child2.child3
```

and now I want to edit this 4 level deep JSON, so want to do something like:

```
// how to do the following
String oldVal = jsonObj.getString("parentObj.child1.child2.child3");
jsonObj.put("parentObj.child1.child2.child3", "newVal");
```

**Note:**

- the level of json depth can be 1 < length < 100.
- user can put any relevant value in property file. If the key do not exist in JSON, need to catch exception.
- incoming json format is NOT fixed.

Comment: you can use json path. this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/34117168/9050514

Comment: you can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64422516/how-to-update-json-value-using-java/64424791#64424791 (and use just committed JsonEventPump instead of implementing of full JsonParserListener interface)